# server side alert message that shows unwanted when get back and reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, alert

I have a submit button and below is the code in the onClick event :

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Submitted')", true);
}
```

This code works.

But the problem is when user go to next page by this:

```
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
```

and when click backspace to get back to page1 and,

before the reload,

the following message box appears!!

```
this problem happened again when we refresh(F5) the page1 after submiting
```

how will I solve this?

I tried:

```
 1. if(isPostback)// before the alert
 2. string message = "Submitted";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
    sb.Append("alert('");
    sb.Append(message);
    sb.Append("')};");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

In such case, you can implement a special code block to detect browser refresh as

```
private bool refreshState;
private bool isRefresh;

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    object[] AllStates = (object[])savedState;
    base.LoadViewState(AllStates[0]);
    refreshState = bool.Parse(AllStates[1].ToString());
    if (Session["ISREFRESH"] != null && Session["ISREFRESH"] != "")
        isRefresh = (refreshState == (bool)Session["ISREFRESH"]);
}

protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    Session["ISREFRESH"] = refreshState;
    object[] AllStates = new object[3];
    AllStates[0] = base.SaveViewState();
    AllStates[1] = !(refreshState);
    return AllStates;
}
```

In the button submit you can do it as

```
protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isRefresh == false)
        {
            Insert Code here
        }
}
```